# I want my div to display block when i increment an element

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to turn my div to `display: block` when I increment by clicking the 'add' button.

I am using jQuery. My problem is that when I click the add box it doesn't change the `display`

```js
var num = 0;

if ($('.selected-news').is(':empty')) {
  $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "none");
} else {
  $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "block");
}

$('.addbutton').click(function() {
  $(".selected-news").html(function(i, val) {
    return +val + 1
  });
})

$('.subbutton').click(function() {
  $(".selected-news").html(function(i, val) {
    return +val - 1
  });
})
```

```css
.addbutton,
.subbutton {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-pick-box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
}

p.news-picked {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addbutton">
  ADD
</div>
<div class="subbutton">
  SUBTRACT
</div>
<div class="news-pick-box">
  <p class="news-picked">You have selected <span class="selected-news"></span> news</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var num = 0;
if ($('.selected-news').is(':empty')) {
  $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "none");
} else {
  $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "block");
}
$('.addbutton').click(function(){
  if (!$('.news-pick-box').is(":visible")) {
    $('.news-pick-box').show();
  }
  num++;
  $('.selected-news').html(num);
})
$('.subbutton').click(function(){
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;
  }
  if (num === 0) {
    $('.news-pick-box').hide();
  }
  $('.selected-news').html(num);
})
```

```css
.addbutton, .subbutton {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.news-pick-box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
}
p.news-picked {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addbutton">ADD</div>
<div class="subbutton">SUBTRACT</div>
<div class="news-pick-box">
 <p class="news-picked">You have selected <span class="selected-news"></span> news</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But please can you help me edit it that when it reaches 0 it stops decrementing and it display will be 0 until it increments back to 1 thanks

Comment: Yses just did it :)

Comment: @TimilehinOsazeAdegbulugbe please check my answer

Comment: @Sandwell you if (num >= 0) {
      num--;
    }
will pass num at -1

Comment: was fixing it :) @ChristopheDebove

Comment: @ChristopheDebove my problem with your code is it is not working properly for what i want to use it for and it is impossible for me to get a negative for what i will use it

Comment: @TimilehinOsazeAdegbulugbe it's okay :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;
function refreshSelectedNewsContent(){
 $(".selected-news").html((num>0?num:""));
    if ($('.selected-news').is(':empty')) {
    $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "none");
} else {
    $('.news-pick-box').css("display", "block");
}
}
$('.addbutton').click(function(){ num++; refreshSelectedNewsContent();  })
$('.subbutton').click(function(){if(num>0) num--; refreshSelectedNewsContent(); })
refreshSelectedNewsContent();
```

Please try this code. 
it assures num cannot be negative, and the block is displayed only if num is positive.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: @TimilehinOsazeAdegbulugbe great! you can vote up and accept this answer ^^